# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) hanging from java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, struts

Please, help me out this problem.

When I run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` from Java, the Java process itself is hanged without continue further process. I am setting heap size 1028mb to execute java process but in drive I have less space (say 1.4 GB free memory).

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly you are executing?

Comment: what is the cmd here?